# ng-repeat element only populated after second time running function

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have an ng-repeat element that is only populated the second time I press a button. The button makes a GET call to an API, a JSON response is received and a $scope.movies is set equal to the JSON.

```
$scope.movies = [];
$scope.searchMovie = function()
var params = {
query: 'monsters',
include_adult: true
}
tmdb.call("/search/movie", params, 
function(e){
$scope.movies = e;
}, 
function(e){
console.log("Error" + e)
});
```

$scope.searchMovie is connected to a button

Comment: What is `tmdb` ? My guess is a 3rd party service that's not triggering a `$digest` cycle - hence no view update.

Answer (score 3):

The reason why it doesn't update, is that Angular works with something called Digest cycles.  If you are giving a callback to a 3rd party library it won't trigger an angular digest, in which case you need to trigger one yourself.  I suggest reading more info here:

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope

The basic ways to trigger a digest are through $scope.$apply , $scope.applyAsync, and $timeout.   I suggest you read up on these concepts because they will be very important down the road.

Comment: Thanks! I put $scope.$apply after $scope.movies = e;

Comment: I knew that it had something to do with the content not refreshing the first time.